# How do I sanitze? Pose Library: Error: Potentially corrupt library, run 'Sanitze' operator to fix.

Tags: error

I deleted some bones that are now keyframed and underlined in red the Action Editor. I assume that is why I have this message:

Potentially corrupt library, run 'Sanitze' operator to fix.

I never sanitized anything in Blender nor do I know where it is or what it does.

I tried hitting Make Actions Suitable that makes 228 poses? so that's not it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you do is hit the 'lifesaver' icon on the right hand side. Problem fixed.

Comment: Did not work for me. I think this error occurred when i renamed the initial Pose.?

Comment: this doesn't do anything for me. Is this the actual sanitize operation or is there a way to actually follow what the program is asking?

Answer (score 2):

The Sanitize button (and command) did not fix the problem for me.

However, this did:

- In Object mode I selected the armature.
- I switched to Pose mode, and entire armature was selected.
- I hit the spacebar to pull up the command browser, and typed in "pose" to filter the list of commands.
- I had tried all the top ones, and it "felt" like I needed to do
  something to the "PoseLib" so I chose "PoseLib Add Pose"

The error is now cleared, and I have a Pose Library with a single "Pose" in it.

Blender 2.8 beta

Comment: Cleared the error for me too. 

In my case i want to delete the pose library cause i had 2 empty and they followed in to Unity.

To clear my pose library i had to choose it on Action Editor and then looking under the Scene collection/outliner view, it showed up under Animation data section next to your rig/mesh, i pressed delete. 

Seems to have cleared it up.